# How do you make video look natural?

Tags: video, video-recording, video-capture

I want the videos that I will shoot to feel natural and I don't know what I have to do.

The research I did in the internet says aperture of our eyes are around F/8 in bright conditions and around F/2 in the dark so what aperture should I use for realistic depth of field? .

As far as I learned. The filmmakers use the shutter speed of 1/48 for 24 FPS movies and these movies feel natural to my eyes so what shutter speed I should use?

I have read any FPS can be received by the eye but for some reason. Every 60 FPS video I have ever watched in my life feels like plastic fruit and the internet says it's because we got used to the low FPS moviesthrought our lives do what FPS I should use?

Bit irrevelant but I did some research and it points out the classic 4:3 aspect ratio is actually closest to our vision so should I shoot in 4:3 aspect ratio?

So what is the best way to get that "realistic and natural feeling" in the videos with a 30 FPS APS-C camera?

Comment: What is the relation between 30 fps and PAL? Make the question more coherent and put spaces, commas and periods in the right places.

Comment: @RustyCore when I was searching why 60 FPS videos was feeling anormal. The answers were about how we used to the videos around 24 and 30 FPS and I think its the reason why anything above 30 FPS feels so anormal. The only source I have is a commie site named quora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much found it out yourself.

Use 24FPS, 1/48, Aperture around f4. (Depending on your sensor size)

You really can't get a 1:1 look as our eyes have a diffrent way to see the world than a camera. But those settings will feel natural when used right.

Also think about how you film, many people say shoulder rigs feel the most natural as you have a slight wobble.

For me shoulder rig + lens stabilizer has done the job.

Then, keep in mind how the scene looked so you can match the colors.

Comment: Can you give me a chart for aperture size and sensors?

Comment: Also is it possible to make two cheap DSLR 3d camera by putting them next to each other? I am planning to buy 1300D if that helps.

Comment: It is pretty simple. The smaller your sensor (Going biggest: FF-> APS-C -> MFT smallest) the less depth of field you'll get. But I'd guess for most sensors f4 will do the job. BUt you could go for shallower DOF, for example F2.8 as we don't really persieve DOF the same as a camera.

Comment: Not directly. For real/good 3D the cameras need to move apart from each other, so you would need a rig that could do that. Otherwise the 0 Point will allways be at the same position which won't look natural. Generally tho, 3D doesn't really make it look/feel more natural.